# Kotlin/Android app crashes without a Stack Trace

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've encountered a situation where anything that runs in a coroutine (database queries, network requests or response processing) and fails at some point, simply crashes the app without any logs at all. Is it the expected behavior or do I have something misconfigured?

Here's a simple piece of code that reproduces the error.
Nothing changes with different Dispatchers.

[image: Code]

This is the only output I'm getting, followed by app termination

[image: Output]

And these are the dependencies I'm using, the latest version at the moment of writing.

[image: Dependencies]

It's also reproducing in a simple CLI app without the Android framework.

Edit: Just to make it clear. I'm not trying to see the Exceptions that I'm throwing. I'm trying to get some output when my app crashes because of an unknown reason.

Edit2: To add some clarity, here is another example of the situation without any "throw" statements.

[image: Scenario 2]

[image: Output 2]

Answer (score 1):

Since the exception in happening inside the coroutine, it makes sense to find it there also. Just surround it with `try`/`catch` and you will see the magic:

```
GlobalScope.launch{
  try{
   print("Your printing message")
   throw Exception("Message here")
  }catch(exception: Exception){
   exception.printStacktrace()
   }
 }
```

Comment: Does it make sense? If I were to throw an Exception in another Thread, the app would crash WITH a Stack Trace in the logs.
Wrapping every single coroutine block in a try/catch doesn't sound like the right thing to do.
And the fact that I can't see WHY the app has crashed doesn't feel right.